# How do I mount "drive/MyDrive" as root in Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, gdrive

I mount my Google Drive in Colab like this:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Now when I want to unzip the file "tommuddi.zip" which resides in the folder "drive/MyDrive/"

I have to access it using "drive/MyDrive/tommuddi.zip" which is cumbersome:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = 'drive/MyDrive/tommuddi.zip'

with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
  zip.extractall()
  print('Done')
```

Instead, I would like to access is using

```
file_name = 'tommuddi.zip'
```

How could I make it so that Colab assumes that "MyDrive" is the root so that the above works?

When I try this...

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/MyDrive')
```

... it throws the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-c0fc2c3766a0> in <module>()
      1 from google.colab import drive
----> 2 drive.mount('/content/drive/MyDrive')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/drive.py in _mount(mountpoint, force_remount, timeout_ms, use_metadata_server, ephemeral)
    285             ': timeout during initial read of root folder; for more info: '
    286             'https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#drive-timeout')
--> 287       raise ValueError('mount failed' + extra_reason)
    288     elif case == 2:
    289       # Not already authorized, so do the authorization dance.

ValueError: mount failed
```

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Got it: One has to use cd drive to go to that directory:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd drive/MyDrive
```

After doing that, we are in the MyDrive directoy, and we can access its files directly.